# Problems running Android virtual machine from avd manager

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have installed and set up Eclipse and the plugin ADT in order to work with the Android SDK. So far so good.

However, when I try to launch a VM for any Android platform that I choose (e.g. Android 3.2), I just get the skin launched together with a keyboard console and phone buttons; it seems to boot up to a state and then does nothing but displays the android logo on the main VM screen and that's all it does — nothing else, no VM functionality!

What's going on? Have I missed out some step?

I am working on a Windows 32 bit machine with a Intel dual core 1.5 GHz CPU and 1 GB of RAM.

Comment: Please add details of your PC - right now it sounds like @hakiko is right, your PC is probably of too low a spec to be running the Android emulator. Remember, it has to do on the fly conversion from Dalvik bytecode, to ARM machine code, to x86 machine code, not to mention the video emulation. This is a little different for the x86 emulator images, but they are only available for Gingerbread (2.3.x) so does not apply in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer can not be enough for AVD. That was my problem before. RAM and CPU are very important for an Android developer.

Answer (score 0):

How long do you wait? Sometimes it takes a few minutes.